# PhoneGap Android app is crashing after adding urbanairship to config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

I have an android app which is built using phoneGap. We want to add push notification to our app and we decided to try urbanairship.

I am currently stuck with an issue where my mobile is crashing when launching the application after I add the following to my phonegap config:

```
<!-- Urban Airship plugin for Push notifications -->
<gap:plugin name="com.urbanairship.phonegap.pushnotification" version="2.7.0" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.production_app_key" value="***" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.production_app_secret" value="***" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.development_app_key" value="***" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.development_app_secret" value="***" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.enable_push_onlaunch" value="true" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.in_production" value="false" />
<preference name="com.urbanairship.gcm_sender" value="***" />
```

I followed this documentation: http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/phonegap.html

There is no build error on PhoneGap.
I am running Android 4.3 and the current version of Phonegap is 3.7.0. 
I would appreciate if you could make some suggestions of what could be wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Without any logs its impossible to tell. You are using an older version of the plugin with an older version of PhoneGap. Are you able to upgrade to a newer PhoneGap 5 with PhoneGap Android 4? If so you can use the latest version of the plugin here - https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push